# Observable or Array for list in Angular view

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs5

I've made this simple WebApp that ask for an Array to a server using HttpClient,

Here is the service I used:

```
      /** Day Configuration **/
  getDayConfiguration(day: number | string): Observable<DayConfiguration[]> {

    return this.http.get<DayConfiguration[]>(this.dayConfigurationUrl+'?idweekDay='+day)
      .do(data => console.log(data)) // eyeball results in the console
      .catch(this.handleError);

  }
```

this service is injected in a component which use it in ngOnInit()

```
  private daySettings:DayConfiguration[];

     ngOnInit() {

        this._route.paramMap.switchMap((param) =>{

          return this._apiIwuService.getDayConfiguration(param.get('day'))

        }).subscribe(dayConf=>{

          this.daySettings=dayConf;

        });

      }
```

then I use it in the View with *ngFor

```
  <li  *ngFor="let daySetting of daySettings let i=index">
```

this way it is easy to remove an item from the list showed to the user, ny simply removing the Item (daySettings) form the Array

```
delete(_daySetting: DayConfiguration, index: number){

    this._apiIwuService.deleteDayConfiguration(_daySetting.id)
    .subscribe(()=>{

      this.daySettings.splice(index, 1);

    })

  }
```

if I do the same whitout "transfoming" the Observable into the array how can I delete the elment form the Observable? Is this the correct way to handle this kind of situation?

Comment: What do you mean without transforming the observable into an array? What is wrong with what you have now? What is not working?

Comment: .subscribe(dayConf=>{  this.daySettings=dayConf;}); Here I'm getting the Array. If I do something like:
this.daySettings$=this._route.paramMap.switchMap( (param: ParamMap) =>
        this._apiIwuService.getDayConfiguration(param.get('day')));

where:   private daySettings$: Observable<DayConfiguration[]>;
and in the View: *ngFor="let daySetting of daySettings | async

It also work but I cannot remove the anyting form daySettings$

So my question is still the same, is my solution the correct one or there is a way to remove the Item form the observable. Thanks anyway